# Swift Framework: Umbrella header '[...].h' not found

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

In a custom framework containing both **Objective-C** and **Swift** code, the Swift compiler throws the following error:

```
[build_path]/unextended-module.modulemap:2:19: error: umbrella header 'bugtest.h' not found
  umbrella header "bugtest.h"
                  ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'bugtest'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This will happen, when the `Always Search User Paths` setting is enabled for the Framework target.

Setting it to `No` will resolve that error.

IMHO this is a bug in the Swift Compiler and I have filed a radar with Apple.
See [rdar://21038443](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6082318405992448)

Comment: Thanks!  This is the one that got me, too.

Comment: This worked for me. An additional symptom is that it failed immediately after a clean, but succeeded if you retried without cleaning.

Answer (score 289):

This usually happens after a project rename or something like that. The problem is that the umbrella header is no longer listed as a **Public** header. Check the attached image to see how to fix this.

[image: Fix]

Comment: Just a note to future readers that to see the 'Headers' section of 'Build Phases' at all you need to click on a Pod target. Main app target will not list a 'Headers' section.

Comment: This totally fixed it.  Thank you.  This should be the approved answer.

Comment: For me - access level was public but it also fails on umbrella not found.
I did move the "Headers" section of the "Build phases" to the top and it started to work.

Comment: My umbrella header was already public. Moving the section to the top didn’t help either.

Comment: If you have been doing a project rename/re-organise then check the header settings of the original as XCode seems to take a best guess based on the files. I had 6 project level headers showing but the original project showed I needed two of them at public level and none of the others.

Comment: This answer helped me but didn't actually solve the problem for me, i. e. `umbrella header not found.` I ended up deleting the header file from the Headers build phase and adding it back (making sure it was `public` again). _That_ is what finally worked for me.

Comment: I was having similar issue when Carthage updated one of my imported frameworks. I guess XCode is having troubles to keep an eye for the referenced framework path changes. Simple XCode restart fixed the issue for me.

Comment: For me the header was in both "Project" and "Public" sections. And I had to **remove** it from the "Project" section.

Answer (score 56):

In Xcode 7 Beta, with Swift 2, it will also happen if your Framework Header is not declared as "Public"

For instance, I had a Cocoa Touch Framework with a "Project" visibility for the header file, and the error "Umbrella Header ... not found" for all Swift files in my project, once I had the header "Public", the error went away

Comment: In my case, when I encountered this issue, this answer seemed like the "more correct" answer, and it worked for me.

Comment: I concur. This is the correct answer. Check that the <project>.h file has the right target membership and access level (public).

Comment: @Shadow_x99 how do I set the header as "Public", my question is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084291/no-umbrella-header-found-for-target?noredirect=1#comment59813773_36084291

Comment: This is actually a variation of @arturgrigor's answer, except that Xcode it performing the change itself. The end result should be the same.

Answer (score 47):

There's 4 different ways this can happen, ignoring bugs in previous versions of Xcode

- You don't have a umbrella header named $(TARGET_NAME).h in your project
- You have a umbrella header, but it's not set as public. [See arturgrigor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33865771/95309)
- `DEFINES_MODULE`  is not set to `YES`
- `CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES` is not set to `YES`

Comment: A 5th cause that I just found: umbrella_header.h itself must not be checked in any target (just as Info.plist)

Comment: I have everything set correctly in this list, yet it fails.

Comment: another issue my umbrella header was in mytarget/mytarget.h needs to be in the root with the module.modulemap if you are using one

Comment: "DEFINES_MODULE is not set to YES" Great point! Setting it to NO made Xcode not recognize/compile the umbrella header in my project.

Answer (score 20):

For me - access level was public but it also fails on umbrella not found. I did move the "Headers" section of the "Build phases" to the top and it started to work. 
Script to podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    phase_name = 'Headers'
    target.build_phases.each do |phase|
        if (phase.display_name.include? phase_name)
            target.build_phases.unshift(phase).uniq! unless target.build_phases.first == phase
        end
    end
end
```

Have no clue why it is happening. Tried on dummy projects - not happening. Only on big ones with multiple dependencies.
Something with compiling BEFORE copying umbrella headers.

Comment: Moving "Headers" above "Compile Sources" worked for me. xCode 8.2.1.

Comment: Moving the headers phase to the top also worked for me.

Comment: Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end.

Answer (score 14):

Definitely you must to set your framework to public:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the context of that screenshot? What do you click to get there?

Comment: @pkamb It's been a while but I'll answer just in case, you need to open the file (the missing header) in Xcode and then: CMD + Opt + 0 to open the menu on the right, then select the tab Identity and Type

Answer (score 7):

For me setting 'Use Header Maps' to 'NO' resolved the issue

Comment: …and in my case, setting it to YES fixed the problem. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any documentation on this setting, but yes is the default and I'm not sure why it was set to no for one of my targets.

Answer (score 7):

One more solution: After renaming a folder, the old location might still be listed in the project file for the .h file, even if you updated the location via Xcode's side-bar. This old location causes the umbrella-header error.

Simple solution: Remove the reference to the .h file, and re-add. (and then remember to make it public again!)

Answer (score 5):

There's some excellent answers here already. @Shadow_x99's was very helpful. However, if I could be allowed to supplement with my own experience.

An umbrella header is identified automatically in the build process. *It is not a specified in the target's build settings or inherited from the project settings.*

So to avoid this error that - *as of XCode 7* - is as follows;

`warning: no umbrella header found for target 'MyTarget', module map will not be generated`

two important steps must be taken.

Firstly, the umbrella header must have **the same name as the target**. So if your target is a framework named `MyTarget`, there must be a header named `MyTarget.h`.

Secondly, in the build phases for `MyTarget` - as mentioned in that answer - that header file must be listed in the **public section** as detailed above.

Answer (score 5):

I found that with the New Swift Build System and Parallelize Build turned on the scheme I would get errors like in this question. The solution was to link to frameworks that had been imported in the swift source files. (I think previously the app would build because it just happened that the frameworks were linked to something built previously in the serial build queue).

I wrote a script to go through all the imports in all the targets in a workspace and make sure that their frameworks have been linked to in that target.

https://github.com/Jon889/SwiftImportChecker

Answer (score 1):

Your header file needs to be in the [Build Phases/Headers/Public] section.

If your header file is already in the [Build Phases/Headers/Public] section, many times doing the fallowing solved my problem:

1. clean the project
2. move the header file to the "private" or "project" section
3. move the header file back to the "public" section
4. rebuild everything again

Comment: Wow this is the only one that worked out of these dozens of answers and it seems like it would be the least likely, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and none of the suggested answers helped in my case so I'm leaving this here in case someone has the same problem.

I had added a "Run script" in "Build phases" but ended up removing it and that's when I started getting the error.

My solution ended up having to clean the project, rebuild my framework and then my app project built correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by renaming my module.modulemap to moduleXYZ.modulemap and changing the modulemap file name in the project settings

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you have to choose on the targets the framework which is giving you the error, not the project target.
Then compile, and after compiling it will be available on the project target.

Answer (score 1):

None of these fixes above were successful, but after much investigation into cocoapods I discovered this issue was caused by a git configuration where symbolic links were not being created in the git filesystem. These symbolic links are needed to let Xcode know where the headers are for the framework.

The fix:

`git config --global core.symlinks true`

and reset the file system for git `git reset --hard HEAD`

and then do a clean build.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xcode 7.1 and CocoaPods 0.39, there seems to be a swift compiler change that affects some CocoaPods (Nimble, Quick, etc.) Try some of the solutions specified in the this thread: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4420 however, if neither of them work, try using Xcode 7.0.1 or 7.2 beta. You can get both of them here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/.

Edit: In my case, to fix the issue, I also had to downgrade CocoaPods to 0.38.2.

Later edit: It seems not to be related to Xcode 7.1. Just downgrading CocoaPods to 0.38.2 should help:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 0.39
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.38.2
```

Comment: Thanks @Marius Ursache. Following your instructions resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just built the specific framework with it's scheme. And then rebuild the entire project and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

make sure "import paths" in Build Settings includes the file you're trying to include...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem appears to have been with an incomplete installation of Xcode 13.3 (13E113).

Here's the error that lead me to this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accessibility.framework/Modules/module.modulemap:2:19: umbrella header 'Accessibility.h' not found
```

It turns out that the header file was literally missing from within the SDK (inside the Xcode app bundle).  Looking in the `Headers` directory of that `Accessibility.framework` bundle.

This is what it should be:

```
$ ls -l
total 80
-rw-r--r--  7 andrew  staff  12307 Feb 23 06:14 AXAudiograph.h
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  staff   2013 Feb 23 06:57 AXBrailleMap.h
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  staff    402 Feb 23 06:57 AXColorUtilities.h
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  staff   2612 Feb 23 06:57 AXCustomContent.h
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  staff    395 Feb 17 01:04 AXFoundation.h
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  staff   2109 Feb 23 06:57 AXHearingUtilities.h
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  staff    349 Feb 17 01:04 Accessibility.h
```

But on this Mac, that directory is empty:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
```

We aren't yet sure how this happened.  But this particular instance of Xcode is installed in CI, and the installation of Xcode is automated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Header Search Paths (HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS) build setting points to a directory with headers you include in a module.

Answer (score -1):

In my case problem was caused by remove headers script in Build Phases

```
function removeHeaders() {  
    find $BUILD_ROOT/...  -name '*.h' -exec rm -f {} \;  
}  
removeHeaders
```

Deleting this script fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

None of the 9 answers helped me, so I tried to create a new project which I could send to Apple to file a bug. I was surprised that I couldn’t reproduce the issue. I checked the build settings and they were equivalent. Apparently this is some kind of bug.

*If nothing else helps*, try to create a new project and import at least some Objective C & Swift classes from your current project, compare your framework-related build settings to the default values from the new project, and eventually move all files over to the new project.

Answer (score -2):

I've been working on it for a whole day,but it's worth it.I tried all the ways [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355133/swift-framework-umbrella-header-h-not-found) but I didn't solve it. I created a new project, an experiment, and I found out **User Header Search Path** was setted **${SRCROOT}  recursive**, and I changed it to **${SRCROOT} non-recursive**, changed the bridging header path(e.g.   `#import "SVProgressHUD.h"`     ->   `#import "Pods/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h"`), the error went away.

Answer (score -2):

Remove these files from project's directory.
`.xcworkspace` `pods/` and `podfile.lock`

update the pod and build the project.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by making the Compilation Mode of the problematic framework build settings to Incremental.