# Umbrella header 'CocoaAsyncSocket-umbrella.h' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, cocoapods

With XCode 8.3 or lower, no values of variables are displayed:
[image]

When a variable T is output:

```
lldb> po t
```

Then XCode issues the following error message:

```
warning: Swift error in module testProject.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.
error: in auto-import:
failed to get module 'testProject' from AST context:
error: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testProject-ancfblnaxqmiivgqakzxqkocqfrg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket/CocoaAsyncSocket.framework/Modules/module.modulemap:2:19: error: umbrella header 'CocoaAsyncSocket-umbrella.h' not found
  umbrella header "CocoaAsyncSocket-umbrella.h"
```

I found few pages for this problem:
[Move header on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355133/swift-framework-umbrella-header-h-not-found)

However, it has not solved the problem.
The problem might be CocoaPod. In the previous versions of CocoaPod, there was a problem that Pod Libraries could not be compiled. Because CocoaPod generates the umbrella-headers automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is already answered at [Swift Framework: Umbrella header '[...].h' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355133/swift-framework-umbrella-header-h-not-found), If not please share your podfile and further observations.